# Format 12h time values to 24h in jq output

Tags: json, jq, datetime-format

I have values of the format "h:mm AM"/"h:mm PM" in my json that I get from jq.
Is there a way to parse these 12h formatted values and convert them to 24h ones?

Sample Input:

```
{ "times": [ [ "8:16 AM", "EventA" ], [ "3:19 PM", "EventB" ] ]}
```

Desired Output:

```
{ "times": [ [ "8:16", "EventA" ], [ "15:19", "EventB" ] ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is more generic than actually needed here:

```
def to24h:
    (capture("(?<pre>.*)(?<h>[01][0-9])(?<m>:[0-5][0-9]) *(?<midi>[aApP])[mM](?<post>.*)") //
     capture("(?<pre>.*)(?<h>[0-9])(?<m>:[0-5][0-9]) *(?<midi>[aApP])[mM](?<post>.*)"))

  | (.midi|ascii_upcase) as $midi
  | .pre + (if $midi == "A" then .h else "\(12+(.h|tonumber))" end) + .m + .post ;
```

With this def, you could transform the given input using the filter:

```
.times |= map( map(to24h // .) )
```

or if you want all strings to be checked:

```
walk( if type=="string" then to24h // . else . end)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm quite new to jq. How would I apply the `to24()` function to my json? `jq 'def to24h:...; .times | .[] | to24h([0])' < JSON.file`  doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please see the update.  Have you worked your way through the tutorial at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial ?

Comment: Thank you! I think that's what I'll do next. It's a powerful tool.

Comment: If the time is "12:00 PM" the function converts it to "114:00". So I figured within the if statement there should also be a check for the case if `$pre == 12` and `$h == "2"`. But I can't get the syntax right

Comment: I fixed it so it would display the "12:00 PM" correctly: `def to24h: capture("(?<pre>.*)(?<h>[01]?[0-9])(?<m>:[0-5][0-9]) *(?<midi>[aApP])[mM](?<post>.*)") | (.midi|ascii_upcase) as $midi | .h as $h | .pre as $pre | (if $midi == "A" then .h elif $pre == "1" and $h == "2" then "12" else "\(12 + ((.pre + .h) |tonumber) )" end)  + .m + .post ; .times |= map( map(to24h // .) ) `

Comment: The bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Could we use jq's date functions?

```
jq '(.times[] | .[])
    |= ( if test("^\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2} [AP]M$"; "i")
         then ( strptime("%H:%M %p") | strftime("%k:%M") | sub("^ "; "") )
         else . end ) '
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, however all that happens is the AM/PM is removed and a space is added at the front `" 3:19"`

Comment: If you want to pursue this, you could consult the man page for strftime on your system. On mac os, %k is replaced by the hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number (0-23); single digits are preceded by a blank.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to get rid of the blank. Good luck!

Comment: WARNING: `"12:00 AM", "12:00 PM" | strptime("%H:%M %p") | strftime("%H:%M")` yields `"00:00" "12:00"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `strptime` and `strftime` to parse and reformat each time.

```
% jq -c '.times[][0] |= (strptime("%H:%M %p") | strftime("%H:%M"))'
{ "times": [ [ "8:16 AM", "EventA" ], [ "3:19 PM", "EventB" ] ]}
{"times":[["08:16","EventA"],["15:19","EventB"]]}
^C
```

`strptime` produces a list where the hour matched by `%H` is adjusted to 24-hour time based on the modifier matched by `%p`; `strftime` then simply outputs whatever hour it gets.

The hard part isn't the conversion; it's determining which values the conversion should be applied *to*. Here, we're assuming that each time is the first element of the arrays in the array value of the `times` key.

Comment: WARNING: `"12:00 AM", "12:00 PM" | strptime("%H:%M %p") | strftime("%H:%M")` yields `"00:00"
"12:00"`